# Python / Flask / WTForms - iterating through a multiple choice quiz

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am still very new to python and I am currently working on a multiple choice quiz.  Each quiz could have a different number of questions and each question could have a different number of choices.  However, with this said, I could use a fixed number of choices such as four.

I have a database:

```
class Question(Base):
  """
  a record for each question for the quizes
  """
  __tablename__ = "questions"

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  book_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("books.id"), unique=False, nullable=False)
  chapter_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("chapters.id"), unique=False, nullable=False)

  question = Column(String(128), unique=False, nullable=False)
  choice1 = Column(String(128), unique=False, nullable=False)
  choice2 = Column(String(128), unique=False, nullable=False)
  choice3 = Column(String(128), unique=False, nullable=False)
  choice4 = Column(String(128), unique=False, nullable=False)
  correct = Column(Integer, unique=False, nullable=False)

  def __repr__(self):
    return "< Question - id: {} book_id: {} chapter_id: {} question: {}  {} {} {} {} {} {} >".format(
        self.id,
        self.book_id,
        self.chapter_id,
        self.question,
        self.choice1,
        self.choice2,
        self.choice3,
        self.choice4,
        self.correct
    )
```

I am able to get this done by:

- setting a fixed number of form fields within WTForms

```
class QuizForm(Form):
  q1 = RadioField(validators=[InputRequired()])
  q2 = RadioField(validators=[InputRequired()])
  q3 = RadioField(validators=[InputRequired()])
  q4 = RadioField(validators=[InputRequired()])

  cancel = SubmitField("Cancel")
```

- using the RadioField within WTForms which restricts the response to one answer per question.
- setting the choices for each question separately:

```
form = QuizForm(request.form)
  form.q1.choices = [
    ("1", questions[0].choice1),
    ("2", questions[0].choice2),
    ("3", questions[0].choice3),
    ("4", questions[0].choice4)
  ]
  form.q2.choices = [
    ("1", questions[1].choice1),
    ("2", questions[1].choice2),
    ("3", questions[1].choice3),
    ("4", questions[1].choice4)
  ]
  . . .
```

- displaying each question and choices separately:

```
<div class="grid-quiz">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>{{ questions[0].question }}</p>
  <p></p>
  <div class="grid-quiz">
    {% for q1 in form.q1 %}
      <p>{{ q1(class="quiz-input") }}</p>
      <p>{{ q1.label(class="quiz-label") }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
<div class="grid-quiz">
  <p>2</p>
  <p>{{ questions[1].question }}</p>
  <p></p>
  <div class="grid-quiz">
    {% for q2 in form.q2 %}
      <p>{{ q2(class="quiz-input") }}</p>
      <p>{{ q2.label(class="quiz-label") }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
. . .
```

As I said, this works, but it doesn't feel efficient.  I've spent time trying to find ways to use dicts, nested dicts, lists, nested lists, and more, but I haven't been able to make anything work.

Any and all guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: You could return a list of dictionaries in the `form` object

Comment: @IshanJoshi, thank you for responding.  While I understand what a list of dictionaries is, I do not know how to use it in this application.  Could you please provide an example?  If it includes a variable number of choices per question, what would I need to do within WTForms?  I believe there needs to be a direct relationship between the fields defined within WTForms and the fields in the HTML form.

Comment: In cases like this one. I would not use forms but manipulate the front-end using JavaScript. You can render your template then use jQuery to listen to clicks and then use Ajax to get the correct response if you don't want to render it with the questions. Or you can go further and use JS templates and get questions in form of JSON.